# Calling a web service from SQL Server 2017 - sp_OAMethod - A connection with the server could not be established

Tags: ole, sql-server-2017

I am trying to connect to a JSON web service using SQL Server's `sp_OA` methods.

Here's my script (modified from the one [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/importing-json-web-services-applications-sql-server/)):

```
DECLARE @TheURL VARCHAR(255) = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/' ,-- the url of the web service
        @TheResponse NVARCHAR(4000), --the resulting JSON
        @source nvarchar(255),  --error source
        @description nvarchar(255)  --error description
DECLARE @obj INT, @hr INT, @status INT, @message VARCHAR(255);

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT;  --not really sure what ProgID or CLSID this is referencing

SELECT @hr

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @TheURL, false;

SELECT @hr

IF @hr = 0
    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type',
          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    SELECT @hr

    SET @message = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed';

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, '';
    SELECT @hr

    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @obj, @source out, @description out
    SELECT @source, @description

    IF @hr = 0 
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'status', @status OUT;

    IF @status <> 200 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @message = 'sp_OAMethod http status ' + Str(@status), @hr = -1;
    END;

    SET @message = 'sp_OAMethod read response failed';

    IF @hr = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @Theresponse OUT;
    END;

    EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj;

    IF @hr <> 0 
       RAISERROR(@message, 16, 1);
```

I end up getting an error, the source is msxml3.dll and the description is

> A connection with the server could not be established

I'm using SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2012. I've seen some resolutions for Windows Server 2003 and 2008 saying to apply a hotfix, however, I would assume they've fixed that in subsequent versions.

Any ideas on how I could resolve this error?

Comment: @marc_s Then I guess I've misunderstood something from my web search.  The reference was to W2K3

Comment: That would be **Windows Server 2003** - not **SQL Server 2003** .....

Comment: Alright, thanks @marc_s.  The question has been amended.